# Simple Javascript Doesn't Work Right

Tags: javascript

I use the tabber script shown on http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/ to provide a tabbed page. Generally it works well, and my only complaint is that the tabs don't show until the content has fully loaded, and then there is a jump as the screen writes itself properly. (See [www.littlehotels.co.uk/spain/noves.php](http://www.littlehotels.co.uk/spain/noves.php) for an example of what I mean.)

I thought the solution would be to hide the div containing all the tabbed content like this

```
<div class="tabber" id="tabber" style="display:none">
```

and then reveal it with a small javascript function which is called by

```
<body onLoad="ShowTabber()">
```

The javascript itself is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowTabber() {
document.getElementById('tabber').style.display = "block";
 }
</script>
```

My little function appears to stop the external javascript (tabber.js) from working because the page displays the content of all the tabs in line, without the the tabs themselves at the top. This is the same result as if I delete the reference to the external script from the  of the page.

What am I doing wrong?

More explanation:
When the tabber.js file is missing, the  page displays the content of all the tabs one after the other(as you would expect). Running the script as explained above has exactly the same effect; hence I am concluding that the script blocks the main javascript from running.

Comment: are you using .tabs() in jQuery

Comment: Can you plz put the some more explaination ...

Comment: I don't use jQuery. To be honest I keep away from it because I don't understand it. Perhaps it is time to learn.

Napster, I'll edit the OP to try to give more explantion.

Comment: see this explanation and then if you still have a problem ask again http://jsbin.com/ulocef/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
'onLoad': function(argsObj) {
    /* Display an alert only after tab */
    if (argsObj.tabber.id == 'tab') {
      alert('Finished loading tab!');
    }
  }
```

By default select a tab.Then after completion loading that tab it will show a message.

[see here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/example2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved the problem (sort of) with jQuery, but it has now raised another problem.

In response to PSR, I looked more deeply into jQuery. It would have been too complicated to change over to .tabs(), but I did use jQuery to hide and show some divs at the appropriate moments.

I placed a simple little line in fron of the tabber div to show a "Loading" message.

```
<div id="loading" align="center" style="position:relative;top:70px"><h6>Loading ...</h6></div>
```

Then I put this script in the head, under the jQuery line.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tabber").hide();
        $("#loading").hide();
        $("#loading").fadeIn(1000);
     });
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#loading").hide();
        $("#tabber").fadeIn(300);
     });
function checkResize(id){
      var win=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
      alert(win);
}
</script>
```

That works fine, but a couple of the tabs have iframes for their content, and this script breaks autoResize script I use on those iframes. I'll open a new question to see if anyone has an answer to that.